# What is the impact of adding unique=True to a model field without running a migration?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I made a pretty basic change to one of my django models, altering an existing field to use unique=True.

When I run the migration for this, it fails because there is already existing duplicate data for this field.

So my question is, what does this mean exactly?  Does the column for this field enforce unique=True or does it not?

Maybe another way to frame the question is what is the impact of adding unique=True on a field without running the migration?

Answer (score 0):

If the migration has failed that means the change has not been applied to the database, so you should first remove duplicate entries based on the column on which you are trying to enforce unique constraints, adding `unique=True` without running migrations will do nothing

Answer (score 0):

When you add `unique=True`, it means the database cannot have any repeat entries for that field. I will break your question in different parts and explain it to you:

1. When you add `unique=True` but not `makemigrations`, it won't show you any error until you try to add a repetitive value again. But all the previous values will be still there.
2. When you add `unique=True` and run `makemigrations`, and then `migrate` it will not show any error if you do not have any duplicate entries for that field. But it will show you an error if there are duplicate entries. And you will fail to run `python manage.py migrate`.

To overcome case 2, you will have to manually delete the last migration from your folder(it is the migration you added `unique=True`). After that, change/delete the repeated entries. Only after this, you will be able to add `unique=True`.

Hope this answers your question.